# Counting cars on a specific road

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am receiving cordinates from a large number of cars in the city. I would like to associate each car with the nearest road and later count how many cars are on each road. i am using google maps. I would like to know if there is a more efficient approach to what I am doing - I am hand-drawing all major streets and storing the polyline. When I receive a location, I search my database of roads (polylines) and find the nearest road. This is slow because mapping all roads is very difficult and I receive thousands of positions per minute.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you'd better use a GIS-enabled database like [PostGIS](http://postgis.refractions.net/) loaded with a suitable dataset like [OpenStreetMap's data](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Databases_and_data_access_APIs) - if the OpenStreetMap data are of sufficiently high quality for your region and your purpose of course.